# JPA Duplicate key error when auto generating IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am really confused by this error. I looked similar answers but couldn't find much. So after trying to persist an entity I get the following error:

`The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index`

now the weird thing is, that I have set the generation of the IDs to `AUTO` so I don't see how there can be clashes. The entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class demo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @NotNull
    String title;

    @NotNull
    String description;

    //getters & setters. . .
}
```

and I am trying to persist a new item by calling this method:

```
public void addNew(String title, String description){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.setTitle(title);
    demo.setDescription(description);

    em.persist(demo);
}
```

**EDIT:**
To populate my tables I am using a hand written query, straight into the sql database assigning keys 1, 2 and 3. If I have no data in the DB all works fine..

Comment: your class name should be Demo. The id field should be Integer not primitive int. Your Demo class should implement/override hashcode() and equals() methods. Then clear down your target database table and retest.

Comment: it is Demo. just a typo

Comment: Nice, now make the other changes and retest. JPA entities must always implement hashcode() and equals() IMHO.

Comment: I haven't implemented those yet indeed. I don't even know what they are used for. So gonna do some reading and give it a go.

Comment: I disagree with equals and hashcode.

Comment: please feel free to disagree with hashcode() and equals(). You will also be free to face "weird" errors/bugs in your JPA code.

Comment: I did implement those methods for all my entities with no luck though

Comment: "luck" is nothing to do with it. All JPA entities should have hashcode() and equals() implemented. How  else will the JPA provider "know" when objects that represent the same database row are being compared? Have you cleared down you target database table and tested from that state?

Comment: I am populating the DB on every execution using a hand written query (as mentioned in the original post). If I do not run the query, everything works just fine even with my code. The query I am using for that table is: 
`INSERT INTO DEMO
VALUES (1, 'test', 'test'),
(2, 'test', 'test'),
(3, 'test', 'test');`

Comment: jpa can use the the field annotated by @Id to compare, equals() and hascode() are not needed

Comment: with or without doesn't make a different in my case. There is something else behind this issue

Comment: jpa is an API NOT an implementation. It will not provide equals() and hashcode() funtionality JPA requires a JPA PROVIDER such as hibernate https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode?_sscc=t

Comment: @Rakim please edit your question and add the database table and index DDL you employed to define the target table. This wil assist anyone attempting to solve your issue

Comment: @Rakim why are you specifying a value for ID in your SQL insert statement when you want the ID to be generated automatically? INSERT INTO DEMO VALUES (1, 'test', 'test'), (2, 'test', 'test'), (3, 'test', 'test');

Comment: @Hector because if I don't I get `Column null  cannot accept a NULL value.` error  i.e. `INSERT INTO DEMO (TITLE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('test', 'test'), ('test', 'test'), ('test', 'test');`

Comment: @Rakim, in that case you have not defined your target database table correctly. Please add the DDL you used to create your table to your question above.

Comment: @Hector I am not sure what you need me to post (i.e. DLL). The only interaction with the DB is the above query. The creation of the DB is handled automatically from the Demo entity. What am I missing here?

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language (DDL) is a standard for commands that define the different structures in a database. You must create a table in Debry with something like this DDL statement CREATE TABLE students
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(1024),
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ; Do not rely on "creation of the DB is handled automatically from the Demo entity."

Answer (score 0):

by the way, never use `int` as PK, but `Integer`, so unassigned (`null`) exists. My guess is `AUTO` doesn't work as you expect and `int`s default `0` is used multiple times.

Comment: assignment works fine. It increments on every addition. Is just that it does not behave well with existing in the DB values

Comment: of course not. The id might get generated by an db generator or by hibernates table sequences - both have no idea about your existing PK values.

Comment: So what is the way to "have an idea" about them?

Comment: You would never IDentify a record by null as null is not equal to null. So null ID is useless.

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE* from the comments it is a Derby database. I think the problem is that you created the table with `GENERATED DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` without a `START WITH` clause. Try with a `START WITH 10` or a value at least larger than 3 when you create the table. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO ( 
    ID bigint PRIMARY KEY
        GENERATED DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10, INCREMENT BY 1),
    TITLE varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION varchar(250) NOT NULL
)
```

---

*UPDATE* Answer to question in comments about about configuring column from entity.
Added [`@Column` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) for the `id`. Something like this I should do it. *Note: NOT TESTED!*

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id" columnDefinition="BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL", nullable="false"
private int id;
```

Comment: strange, what database are you using for persistence?

Comment: Ok, then `IDENTITY` should work... hmm, a possibility would be that the column has `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` and not `GENERATED ALWAYS`. The former does not guarantee uniqueness. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html

Comment: I am not sure how to check and fix that. Is it configurable from within the entities?

Comment: Ok, you can do this with the @Column annotation. Updated the answer.

Comment: yes. The problem was that netbeans, no matter what the contents of the DB are will always start assigning IDs from index 1. So all I did to make this work was changing that init value to a larger one (i.e. 50). However this is something that is automatically handled when I will deploy the app so the problem is only a matter of IDE and its settings

Comment: Ok, good to hear that you got it to work! Just out of curiosity, are you using JavaDB (derby) when you deploy the app also?

Comment: Sometimes you need SEQUENCE, because IDENTITY disables batch queries in JPA.